# Angular Component Interaction: Parent to Child

Tags: angular

I see that Parent to Child component interaction can be done using localVariable or @ViewChild. Which is the best way to use and why?

Here is the code from angular site I am trying to understand the localVariable

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-countdown-timer',
  template: '<p>{{message}}</p>'
})
export class CountdownTimerComponent implements OnDestroy {

  intervalId = 0;
  message = '';
  seconds = 11;

  ngOnDestroy() { this.clearTimer(); }

  start() { this.countDown(); }
  stop()  {
    this.clearTimer();
    this.message = `Holding at T-${this.seconds} seconds`;
  }

  private clearTimer() { clearInterval(this.intervalId); }

  private countDown() {
    this.clearTimer();
    this.intervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
      this.seconds -= 1;
      if (this.seconds === 0) {
        this.message = 'Blast off!';
      } else {
        if (this.seconds < 0) { this.seconds = 10; } // reset
        this.message = `T-${this.seconds} seconds and counting`;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CountdownTimerComponent } from './countdown-timer.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-countdown-parent-lv',
  template: 
  <h3>Countdown to Liftoff (via local variable)</h3>
  <button (click)="timer.start()">Start</button>
  <button (click)="timer.stop()">Stop</button>
  <div class="seconds">{{timer.seconds}}</div>
  <app-countdown-timer #timer></app-countdown-timer>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['../assets/demo.css']
})
export class CountdownLocalVarParentComponent { }
```

In the second code snippet, I see that they are using #timer local variable to access child class methods in the parent component. Is there any specific reason to use localVariable instead of @ViewChild

Comment: Your question looks very broad, could you share specific problem you are facing or trying to get answer of.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Angular  @Input() and @Output() properties

[input-and-output-properties](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#input-and-output-properties)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to interact with the components. However if you want to interact with the components the simplest way is to use @Input and @Output decorator.If you are new to Angular try using @Input() and @Output decorator for interactions between components. You can also make use of services in Angular for component interaction or the one you mentioned above. Please check the link for better understanding.

[component-interaction](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-input-and-output-example#:%7E:text=%40Input%20decorator%20binds%20a%20property,to%20act%20as%20input%20property.)